# Trying to update LokiJS db but getting 'Trying to update unsynced document' error

Tags: javascript, lokijs

Trying to dynamically add entries of people and fruit that they own in Loki JS but I keep getting the `Trying to update unsynced document. Please save the document first by using insert() or addMany()` error. Anyone have any ideas of how to do this successfully?

I've logged the values coming in and they match what is found in the db already.

```
const loki = require('lokijs');

const db = new loki('loki.json');

const peopleAndFruits = db.addCollection('peopleAndFruits');

peopleAndFruits.insert({ dbname: 'person', fruits: 10 });

const createOrInsertUserToDb = (name, fruitNumber) => {
    const data = peopleAndFruits.find({ dbname: name });
    console.log('db entry before updated ', data[0].dbname);
    if (data[0].dbname !== name) {
        // console.log('this person did not exist in our database');
        peopleAndFruits.insert({ dbname: name, fruits: fruitNumber });
    } else {
        // console.log('previously existing entry');
        peopleAndFruits.update({
            dbname: data[0].dbname,
            fruits: Number(fruitNumber + data.fruits),
        });
    }
    // console.log('data after update or insert', peopleAndFruits.data);
    db.saveDatabase();
};
```

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon this question, the problem is that when calling `peopleAndFruits.update`, the doc you pass needs to be an existing item in the collection, that means it has to have a `$loki` id. In your case, you could either go with

```
peopleAndFruits.update({
  ...data[0],
  fruits: +fruitNumber + fruits;
});
```

or

```
peopleAndFruits.findAndUpdate({$loki: data[0].$loki}, item => {
  item.fruits = +fruitNumber + fruits;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to select the doc first from the collection preferably by its unique id:

```
const loki = require('lokijs');

const db = new loki('loki.json');

const peopleAndFruits = db.addCollection('peopleAndFruits', {unique: '_id'});

peopleAndFruits.insert({_id:"spy_007", dbname: 'person', fruits: 10 });

let doc = peopleAndFruits.by("_id", 'spy_007') //select the doc first to be updated

doc.dbname = "John"  //update its values
doc.fruits = 100   //update its values

peopleAndFruits.update(doc) //update the collection
```

Comment: Excellent answer!